# Run jar file in command prompt when onclick event in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

sample source code which I tried in Javascript.

```
<button onclick="window.open('file:///D:/nodejs/test.jar')">Run Test</button>
```

How to achieve this in Nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

I think that will not work because the `window.open` command is executed on the client and not the node.js server.

You need something like the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to run the bat file on the server.

Comment: Hi xander. I need like when click the button run the jar file to run in command prompt. could you help me.

Comment: I guess you need to send a command to the server so it can execute it with a child_process or another way. To send a command you can use a simple GET-request or AJAX or whatever, that depends on your application. Also what your JAR file does, if it's an interactive console application it can get complicated.